# Get the object passed as the properties-argument in the animate-method

Tags: jquery

For a dom-element wrapped in a jquery-object I need to get the current position OR if it's currently being animated I need to instead get its end-position. Is there any way of accessing the object passes as the properties-argument in the jquery.animate()-method? Or would I need to store those objects somewhere so I later can look up where a given dom-element is animating towards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out one way to do it:

For instance if I want to to animate an object 50px to the right of its current position or where it's going towards I can do:

```
var currentX=myJqueryObject.css("left");//Get the position it's currently at
myJqueryObject.finish();//finish the animation so its position instantly gets set to where its animating towards
var endx=parseInt(myJqueryObject.css("left"));//get its position now. If it wasn't animating when finish() was called then the call didn't change anything.
myJqueryObject.css("left",currentX);//set its position back to where it was before calling finish()
myJqueryObject.animate({left:endx+50});//now animate it 50px to the right of its current position or 50px to the right of the position it was animating towards
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard arguments to the "animate" method is a "complete" callback.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Inside of a "complete" function, you can get the current element by wrapping "this" in a selector like so:

```
$("div").animate({
    "width": '500'
}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"black"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ana5R/

There is also a "progress" function that is called at each step, depending on what your needs are.

Comment: Not quite sure if you got me right. I did figure out a solution though which I posted